# Plugin filter on the content, how to change and insert manually

Tags: wordpress, filter

I'm using a plugin that generates voting arrows on posts and inserts them with a filter just before the_content.

This is somewhat undesirable because it doesn't let me achieve granular control over the position of the element on the page.

Filter looks like this:-

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpeddit_content_filter', 20 );
function wpeddit_content_filter( $content ) {

    if(!is_page() && !is_admin()){
    $newcontent = epic_reddit_voting();
    $content = $newcontent . $content;
    }
    // Returns the content.
    return $content;
}
```

and the function looks like this:-

```
function epic_reddit_voting(){
    global $wp_query,$post,$wpdb, $current_user,$query_string;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $wpdb->myo_ip   = $wpdb->prefix . 'epicred';

    $postvote = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'epicredvote' ,true);
            if($postvote == NULL){
                $postvote = 0;
    }

            //again if IP locked set the fid variable to be the IP address.
    if(get_option('epicred_ip') == 'yes'){
        $ipAddr = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
        $fid = "'" . $ipAddr . "'"; 
    }else{
        $fid = $current_user->ID;
    }

            $query = "SELECT epicred_option FROM $wpdb->myo_ip WHERE epicred_ip = $fid AND epicred_id = $post->ID";
            $al = $wpdb->get_var($query);
            if($al == NULL){
                $al = 0;
            }
            if($al == 1){
                $redclassu = 'upmod';
                $redclassd = 'down';
                $redscore = 'likes';
            }elseif($al == -1){
                $redclassd = 'downmod';
                $redclassu = 'up';
                $redscore = "dislikes";
            }else{
                $redclassu = "up";
                $redclassd = "down";
                $redscore = "unvoted";
            }

             ?>


            <?php wpeddit_post_ranking($post->ID); ?>


            <?php if(!is_user_logged_in() && get_option('epicred_ip') == 'no') { ?>
            <div class = 'logged-in-only'>

            <?php } ?>


            <div class = 'reddit-voting'> 
                <ul class="unstyled">
            <?php  if(!is_user_logged_in() && get_option('epicred_ip') == 'no') { ?>
                    <div class="arrow2 <?php echo $redclassu;?> arrow-up-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" data-red-current = <?php echo $al;?> data-red-like = "up" data-red-id = "<?php echo $post->ID;?>" role="button" aria-label="upvote" tabindex="0"></div>
                    <div class="score2 <?php echo $redscore;?> score-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" data-red-current = <?php echo $al;?>><?php echo $postvote; ?></div>
                    <div class="arrow2 <?php echo $redclassd;?> arrow-down-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" data-red-current = <?php echo $al;?> data-red-like = "down" data-red-id = "<?php echo $post->ID;?>" role="button" aria-label="upvote" tabindex="0"></div>
                    <?php }else{ ?>
                    <div class="arrow <?php echo $redclassu;?> arrow-up-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" data-red-current = <?php echo $al;?> data-red-like = "up" data-red-id = "<?php echo $post->ID;?>" role="button" aria-label="upvote" tabindex="0"></div>
                    <div class="score <?php echo $redscore;?> score-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" data-red-current = <?php echo $al;?>><?php echo $postvote; ?></div>
                    <div class="arrow <?php echo $redclassd;?> arrow-down-<?php echo $post->ID;?>" data-red-current = <?php echo $al;?> data-red-like = "down" data-red-id = "<?php echo $post->ID;?>" role="button" aria-label="upvote" tabindex="0"></div>    
                    <?php }  ?>
                </ul>
            </div>  
            <?php  if(!is_user_logged_in() && get_option('epicred_ip') == 'no') { ?>
            </div>
            <?php } 

}
```

The output that the filter generates is (depending in settings) everything contained within `<div class = 'reddit-voting'> </div>`.

My question is, how do I, without using the filter, which I'd prefer not to use, insert that into my page templates?

Comment: What about inserting `epic_reddit_voting()` in the very templates?

Comment: Oh god, yes, that. ~smacks head on desk~